# Send the attributes received from SAML assertion to a different application

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml, opensaml

I created a spring boot app with SAML2.0 integration with Okta as the IDP. Am able to successfully authenticate using okta and am getting back the required attributes from SAML assertion. Am using SP initiated flow.
Now, I need to send these attributes to another application, which is not using Spring Boot. What is the best way to send the required attributes so that the other application can get the details and authenticate against its own database?

Let's say Application A is spring boot app implementing SAML2.0 and receiving SAML response. Now Application B is another application which needs to receive user profile attributes from Application A and uses it to authenticate on its side.

Can I convert the SAML assertion into a token ? How can I do that ?

Am new to Spring Boot and SAML, so am not sure what are the best options to move forward.

As of now, I have spring boot application with SAML2.0 running successfully.

Comment: *Now Application B is another application which needs to receive user profile attributes from Application A* Why B can't use the IDP on its own?

Comment: Because its a legacy application written in a framework called webobjects which doesn't support SAML2.0 or IDP integration. Or its very complicated to even implement IDP and SAML on that Application B.

Comment: Still, the best option for you is to implement a regular SSO protocol on B, if not SAML then OIDC. The OIDC should be farily easy to implement, even without any available client-side apis.

Comment: Ya but the requirement from a customer is to use SAML. So cannot use OIDC. Thanks though!